# Pastebin, but for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, pastebin

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is a useful online tool to paste snippets of text. [Pastie](http://www.pastie.org/) is a similar tool. Also, [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) is similar except that it also runs the source code, as well as being a general pastebin.

Is there a similar tool, for HTML? To host simple one-page html documents with or without javascript, instead of setting up a freehostia account for the purpose?

Comment: You can create articles on https://telegra.ph/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/

http://jsbin.com/

http://www.webdevout.net/test

Comment: http://jsbin.com seems better than jsfiddle if all you want is HTML. (It doesn't insist on showing all of HTML, CSS, JS and Output at once, and has a convenient way to view the output as a standalone page.)

Comment: jsbin.com would be perfect if it wasn't for this: "If a bin is created by an anonymous user, the full output (that is: with the JS Bin editor stripped away) is only available for 90 minutes after creation. After which the URL will redirect to the editor view." You can register a free account to keep the URL for the raw HTML functional indefinitely.